# Identity transformation without using @*

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

I'm trying to create an xslt transformation affecting only some elements. To leave the other elements and attributes untouched, I'm using following identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that the xslt processor on the server can't process it and is failing with following error:

```
ERROR:  'java.lang.NullPointerException'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.TransletException: java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

It looks like it's some bug with processing the attribute matcher `@*` in the xalan: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2527

I have no way to modify the libraries used for transformation so my question is if there's some way to work around this without specifying all the possible attribute names(which I don't know in advance)

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you only want to transform some elements and you don't have to transform any attributes then you can replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` with `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates/>`. I have no idea whether that fixes the problem with Xalan.

Comment: The problem is with this matcher: `@*`. I can list the attributes by specifying the attribute names like `@att1|@att2|node()`, but that doesn't really solve the problem for me, because I don't have xsds for all the xmls which may go through.

Comment: My suggestion is to try to use `<xsl:template match="*"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` which does not use the attribute wild card in a `match` or `apply-templates`, only in the `copy-of`. That is all I can suggest, other than cosmetical changes like trying to use `attribute::*` instead of `@*`. You will have to try whether anything works and of course a `copy-of select="@*"` might cause the same exception, but as long as you want to use the broken XSLT implementation and the identity transformation there are only a few things you can try to change.

Comment: None of this work unfortunately. `attribute::*` produces the same error and your other suggestion doesn't seem to work for me. You missed `</xsl:copy>` after `<xsl:copy-of..`, right? I guess I'm out of luck then. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: It should have been `<xsl:template match="*"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Tried that, but the problem is there also fo `@*` in select.

Comment: As a last resort, you might want to try whether you can use the interpreter version of Xalan with e.g. `TransformerFactory fact = new com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();` instead of `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc`. But it is probably time to upgrade your XSLT implementation to something less buggy, as the identity transformation or `@*` is too important and too basic for any serious XSLT use.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I have no access to code or libraries. I can only provide xslt.